# Save uploaded file for later use

Tags: javascript, html, file, local-storage

I'm building a music player of sorts. In this program, users can click a button to add a song to their playlist from their filesystem, based on a file input. It works fine if I just want to use a single song - the user clicks the "add song" button, and I can get the data from that to play a song. The problem comes when the user reloads the page. What I want to happen is when the user reloads the page, I can just resume the very same song. Here's some code.

```
var song = manageAddSong.files[0];
```

I need that song variable to be persistent. Can I use localSotrage for this?

```
localStorage.setItem("persistentSong",song);
```

EDIT: I am also very likely going to use a JSON array to store the song data. Can that also be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `localStorage`. However, `localStorage` can only store strings, so you'll need to convert the object to a JSON string:

```
localStorage.setItem("persistentSong", JSON.stringify(song));
```

And to retrieve it later:

```
var song = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persistentSong"));
```

Comment: As it turns out, from a _lot_ of research, this is not possible at all